# merge different IQueryable with and, or, nand or nor

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iqueryable

In my web app i have a advanced search view where the user should be able to create his own search request with a lot of possible search options. These options are created for user readable.
So here is a picture of the user interface:
[image]

In the controller i will create a Linq to Sql query out of this informations.
I already make some prefiltering with an `IQueryable<T>`.

So if i would create a IQueryable for every statement, is it possible to connect them with and/or/nand/nor?

Is there another practice to solve such a problem?

Comment: Take a look at predicatebuilder, maybe (as far as nand and nor can be managed with and and or) : http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: Shame your not using entity framework, entity sql would make this easy.  But there is dynamic linq http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/ not used it my self.